# Kmeans clustering using mahout

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

I am trying to perform kmeans algorithm on data using . The option that has to be passed while running need a path to initial clusters. Can anyone tell me how can we have initial clusters even before starting the algorithm?

```
bin/mahout kmeans \
    -i <input vectors directory> \
    -c <input clusters directory> \
    -o <output working directory> \
    -k <optional number of initial clusters to sample from input vectors> \
    -dm <DistanceMeasure> \
    -x <maximum number of iterations> \
    -cd <optional convergence delta. Default is 0.5> \
    -ow <overwrite output directory if present>
    -cl <run input vector clustering after computing Canopies>
    -xm <execution method: sequential or mapreduce>
```

Comment: [Here](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-run-k-means-clustering-in-mahout.html) is an example to run syntheticcontrol data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Mahout is *slooooow*. If your data fits into main memory, use other tools such as ELKI. They outperformed Mahout for me by far. If your data doesn't fit into main memory: are you sure k-means makes any sense on your data anyway? There is no point in doing a computation that doesn't solve your problem. Start with a sample to first check if it works at all, then scale up. Mahout is a last resort choice: if you absolutely need this to be computed on all your data, and everything else failed, then use Mahout.

B) Read all the documentation... next line in the documentation of Mahout k-means says:

> Note: if the `-k` argument is supplied, any clusters in the `-c` directory will be overwritten and `-k` random points will be sampled from the input vectors to become the initial cluster centers.

In other words: **if** you know the initial cluster centers, supply them via `-c` and do *not* set `-k`. Otherwise **an empty `-c` folder is okay, if you provide `-k`**, the number of cluster centers to sample.